# How can TAB files be created for TIFF and JPEG raster images using QGIS?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, raster-conversion, jpg, tab

Although feature datasets can be exported from QGIS in TAB format, it doesn't seem to be possible to export a raster image, such as a JPEG or a TIFF format raster image from QGIS. Is there a plugin that would enable this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. TAB is a vector format. You should probably be looking for a way to convert raster to vector first.

Comment: .tab is also the way to georeference raster files in MapInfo.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the .tab file that is used for georeferencing raster images is rather simple. It has some headers, then a list of ground control points, and last the coordinate system information. GDAL and QGIS do not write .tab files but with some Python it should not be very difficult. Probably someone has done it already. But if you don't have a very old version of MapInfo there should be no need to write .tab files because MapInfo can read GeoTIFFs directly. MapInfo can create the .tab file when the GeoTIFF is opened if it feels it necessary.

A raster .tab file as an example. See the reference to the not georeferenced image file, list of ground control points with geographical and pixel coordinates, and the CRS string.

```
!table
!version 300
!charset WindowsLatin1

Definition Table
  File "new_4_ed50.tif"
  Type "RASTER"
  (550108.760,4300108.25) (32,44) Label "Pt 1",
  (600243.88,4300191.610) (1032,44) Label "Pt 2",
  (600206.349,4250280.080) (1032,1043) Label "Pt 3",
  (550071.220,4250162.530) (31,1044) Label "Pt 4"
  CoordSys Earth Projection 8, 28, "m", -9, 0, 0.9996, 500000, 0
  Units "m"
```

**EDIT**
This tfw to tab script https://danielbrannstrom.wordpress.com/2010/12/17/create-mapinfo-tab-files-from-tfw-files/ may give some inspiration.